# Glide transformation to choose position of wallpaper?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am using the Glide library for a wallpaper app and I am stuck with the problem that on applying my walls, the only thing I see on my screen is the left side of a given pictures. I would like at least to see the center of the picture, and at best to see the position that I have chosen before I hit "apply". I have tried all three Glide transformations: centerCrop, fitCenter and CenterInside, but my walls remain in the same place. This is my code, based on this document: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transformations.html

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
    .asBitmap()
    .load(passedUrl)
    .centerInside()
    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>()
```

Is it possible to create a custom transformation for Glide to achieve what I want? If not, are there other libraries or methods that would work? I have failed to find any...

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
Glide.load(url).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
     .into(myImageView);
```